# Connection drop in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I am using ubuntu 16.04 for the first time. My system does not connect to my home wifi network but gets connected to other wifi networks. I have put the correct password. What could be the possible reasons?

as asked the output of

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE  802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Ad
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to inclusive the output of `lspci | grep Wireless` (Case sensitive)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your router's settings page and try changing the Wi-Fi channel. Some devices cannot connect to Wi-Fi when the router is automatically set to a different channel.

Also, can you connect to Wi-Fi when booting from a Live CD?

[image: Example]

Comment: I tried your method. I am still facing the same problem.  The connection keeps dropping every now and then.